# Why is Python not printing out the correct answers?

Tags: python, coin-flipping

I cant understand why Python is not printing out how many heads and tails there have been in my coin toss game? and is consistently printing out `0`, `100`

```
# part 2
import random
heads = 0
tails = 0

flip_coin = ['heads', 'tails']

while (heads + tails) < 100:
    flip = random.choice(flip_coin)
    if flip == heads:
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1
print(heads)
print(tails)
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did a mistake here

```
if flip == heads: # You are comparing with the heads count integer variable
```

What you want is

```
if flip == 'heads': # You want to know if it's the string 'heads'
```

> and is consistently printing out 0, 100

Because of that mistake above, if you analyze that if else, because `flip == heads` was always false, you always get have the `else: tails += 1` executed, hence `tails = 100` and `heads = 0`

Comment: Using a strong typed language will prevent this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to put your `heads` under quotes to make it a string, and because of that your if statement is always `false`, hence heads is always 0, and `tails` will always 100.

Try this:

```
# part 2
import random
heads = 0
tails = 0

flip_coin = ['heads', 'tails']

while (heads + tails) < 100:
    flip = random.choice(flip_coin)
    if flip == 'heads':
        heads += 1
    else:
        tails += 1
print(heads)
print(tails)
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to be aware the `heads` (the variable) is not the same as `'heads'` (the string). In any case, there are better (well, more Pythonic) ways to do simple one-of-two selection like this in Python.

You can just use something like the following list comprehension:

```
>>> import random
>>> count = 100
>>> heads = len([1 for i in range(count) if random.randint(0,1) == 1])
>>> tails = count - heads
>>> print(heads, tails)
43 57
```

The expression for `heads` can be broken down to:

- Start with an empty list and run a loop 100 times.
- For each time where a random `0/1` value is `1`,  add 1 to the list.
- Get the list length at the end it's the number of times you flipped 1.

Alternatively, you could populate the list with exactly 100 random `0/1` values and just sum them up:

```
>>> heads = sum([random.randint(0,1) for i in range(100)])
```

That's simpler than the original code snippet I provided but it doesn't show the full power of list comprehension in that it can have transformation, iteration and selection: For example, the following code gives the squares of all positive even numbers less than or equal to 20:

```
>>> [i * i for i in range(1,21) if i % 2 == 0]
[4, 16, 36, 64, 100, 144, 196, 256, 324, 400]
```